# Unable to Upload base64 string to firebase using firebase push

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, push

I'm working on a cordova app project in which i need to upload a image from camera to firebase . I'm getting a base64 string from camera plugin and the same trying to upload to the firebase.

```
$scope.testing = function() {
   var Base64String="hard coded base 64 string";
   var CreateGripRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/testing');
   CreateGripRef.push({ID: Base64String});
}
```

**Problem** : I used regular firebase push method to insert to firebase but it neither alerts any error message nor it adds the node.

However the same code works fine when i upload it from browser instead of genymotion or my android mobile.

Comment: If you add an `onComplete` handler, you can see if something goes wrong: `CreateGripRef.push({ID: Base64String}, function(error) { if (error) { console.log(error); } });` See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html . Most likely is that your image size exceeds the maximum size of a Firebase node value, which is 10MB. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-limitations

Comment: Thanq for your reply i kept the suggested code for error message, But no use im not getting any error mesg too.

Comment: I have tryed this link but its not working. I tryed with a string length it breaks when i try to upload 1289-1288 charecter length string as a value to the node in firebase from mobile : android 4.4 ram 2 GB. (Lenovo A6000 Plus)
https://github.com/brentvatne/snaps

Comment: *Firebase just released a new feature called [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). This allows you to upload images and other non-JSON data to a dedicated storage service. We highly recommend that you use this for storing images, instead of storing them as base64 encoded data in the JSON database.*